# Getting OutOfMemory in RabbitMQ after a while

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, autofac, masstransit

I use RabbitMQ with C#, MassTransit, Autofac.

I have a scheduled(5 sec) job to consume queues.

This job works about 2 hours and then it suddenly stops. When i searched the logs, i found this :

> Scope ---> An exception occurred during bus creation (See inner
>   exception for det ails.) ---> MassTransit.ConfigurationException: An
>   exception occurred during bus  creation --->
>   System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

These are my code block to configure Autofac in MassTransit :

```
builder.Register(context =>
{
    var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Host(new Uri(Globals.QueueUrl), h =>
        {
            h.Username(Globals.QueueUserName);
            h.Password(Globals.QueuePassword);
        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("create_sales_queue",
            ec =>
            {
                ec.Consumer<CreateSalesConsumer>(context);
                ec.UseRetry(p => p.Incremental(10, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)));
            });

    });
    return busControl;
})
    .InstancePerDependency()
    .As<IBusControl>()
    .Named<IBusControl>(GenericIntegrationTask.CreateSalesTask.ToString());
```

These are scheduled job's code :

```
try
{

    var bus = container.ResolveNamed<IBusControl>(GenericIntegrationTask.CreateSalesTask.ToString());
    bus.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    bus.Stop();        
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've had a similar problem, thanks for asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **never** register your `IBus` per dependency or per request. It **must** be a single instance.

You also need to start the bus at your app startup and stop the bus when your app stops.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and @Anton 's,

I have applied suggestions (yet we do have consumers) however i received following error this time which keeps repeating:
    The bus was already started, additional Start attempts are ignored: 
 rabbitmq://192.168.1.1/bus-BNN-NB-0019-PRM.ConsoleApplications.RabbitMQTest-sbgoyynx9txf
dtdobdk5b9tsyi?durable=false&autodelete=true

Comment: Obviously you stat the bus more than once. I wrote in my answer that you should start the bus when your app starts and shut it down when your app closes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that every time you Resolve `IBusControl` instance - you create a new one. But you do not use lifetime scope - this instance isn't collected by GC.

I see two solutions:

1. List item Resolve the `IBusControl` within the lifetime scope. [See here](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/)
2. Register `IBusControl` as a SingleInstance